# How can I unlink my Facebook account from a closed Yahoo account?

Tags: facebook, yahoo

My old Yahoo account has been closed. So, I can't log in with it to unlink the Facebook account or change anything. But I'd like to link the Facebook account to my new Yahoo account.

Answer (score 1):

You can login using any email, username or mobile phone number associated with your account.

Where username is facebook.com/username